# Requests.post throws 110 connection refused error on server but goes through on local laptop

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I get the following error when I try to make a requests.post on my remote ubuntu server

> HTTPConnectionPool(host="", port=91): Max retries exceeded with
>   url: /API/Service/PremiumCalulationForMotor (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

However, the same code (with the same data and headers) goes through when I try from my local ip address.

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Edit: The code that i wrote:

```
import requests

url = "http://someurl:91/pathtoendpoints/"

data = {"some":"xml string"}

headers = {"Content-Type":"application/xml"}

r = requests.post(url = url, headers = headers, data = data)

print(r.text)
```

Comment: I have hidden the url as it is a third party URL

Comment: then you can expect only advice or opinion based solution. Take:1 : is the port you are trying to access is available ?
Is your url(server) granted blocked all unknown ips or mac ?

Comment: Hi @Gahan yes.  The port is available.  The same code runs on my laptop in the localhost environment.  When I move it to the server, the requests.post throws up an error.  I'll edit the post so that I can put the code

Comment: Could it be possible that it is a CORS issue?  If so, any ideas on how we can treat it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

There was a server side firewall issue that prevented the request.post from getting out of the server, thereby causing an error.

I restarted my AWS firewall settings and the issue got fixed.

Regards,
Galeej