# Why am I getting this ERRNO 110 - python requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to know what is the problem when I try to make a request to this URL. Here is my code:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def make_request(Url):
    result = rq.get(Url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, "html.parser")
    events = soup.find_all("a")
    for i in events:
        print(i)
make_request("https://web.archive.org/web/20180507100019/https://bravenewcoin.com/industry-resources/events-calendar/bitcoin-and-blockchain-events/")
```

I think the problem is the URL, in that case what can I do to solve this and parse the content of that website ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I cannot replicate the error, it prints just fine for me

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49234416/getting-errno-110-connection-timed-out-when-trying-to-do-get-requests-in-pyt) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415551/requests-post-throws-110-connection-refused-error-on-server-but-goes-through-on?rq=1). The problem appears to be on your end

Comment: @roganjosh Reaally? maybe It's my setup.

Comment: Your url ist faulty, there are **two** `https://`!!

Comment: @stovfl I already tried without the second https and still not working

Comment: What about @roganjosh hints about Firewall and Proxy?

Comment: I can't replicate the error either, I get 200 response and data in the result. Are you running this on a virtualenv?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the `response` as shown in this [SO:Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343099)

Answer (score 0):

There are two urls in your function,

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20180507100019/
https://bravenewcoin.com/industry-resources/events-calendar/bitcoin-and-blockchain-events/
```

please provide one url at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can request two url once.you appear to need this

```
urls = [
"https://web.archive.org/web/20180507100019/",
"https://bravenewcoin.com/industry-resources/events-calendar/bitcoin-and-blockchain-events/"]
for url in urls:
    make_request(url)
```